# Unable to control iframe dynamically added to a page

Tags: javascript

I have been trying to add an invisible iframe to a page for tracking purposes.
I am not able to control that iframe from the parent page:
Here is the code i have done :

```
try
{
    var frame = document.createElement("iframe");
    frame.setAttribute("src", "http://example.com/frame.php");
    frame.style.width = "0px";
    frame.style.height = "0px";
    frame.style.border = "0px";
    frame.setAttribute("visibility", "hidden");
    frame.setAttribute('id',"awesomeIframe");
    frame.style.display = "none";
    if(document.body != null)
    {
        document.body.appendChild(frame);
    }
    else
    {
        document.head.appendChild(frame);
    }
}catch(e){}
```

How can i modify the js included in the iframe?

Comment: Is it in same domain?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should get the content window of iframe in order to control it.

**remeber**

It generally works when domain and protocol are same. Here is the code below:

```
try
{
    var frame = document.createElement("iframe");
    frame.setAttribute("src", "http://example.com/frame.php");
    frame.style.width = "0px";
    frame.style.height = "0px";
    frame.style.border = "0px";
    frame.setAttribute("visibility", "hidden");
    frame.setAttribute('id',"awesomeIframe");
    frame.style.display = "none";
    if(document.body != null)
    {
        document.body.appendChild(frame);
    }
    else
    {
        document.head.appendChild(frame);
    }
  iframex = document.getElementById("awesomeIframe").contentWindow;
}catch(e){}
```

** iframex = document.getElementById("awesomeIframe").contentWindow;**
Use iframex to control the iframe.